# Remove repetitive paragraphs

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a word document I would like to replace repetitive paragraphs by a single paragraph. The replacement should only be performed between two tags, e.g.

```
text
*start*


more text



*end*


even more text
```

should be replaced by

```
text
*start*

more text

*end*


even more text
```

I tried the following:

```
Dim firstTerm As String
Dim secondTerm As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim selRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
firstTerm = "*start*"
secondTerm = "*end*"
With myRange.Find
  .Text = firstTerm
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .Execute
myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Set selRange = ActiveDocument.Range
selRange.Start = myRange.End
  .Text = secondTerm
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .Execute
myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
selRange.End = myRange.Start
End With

selRange.Select
With Selection.Find
  .Text = "^p^p"
  .Replacement.Text = "^p"
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens

Comment: Do you want to replace repetitive `blank` paragraphs by a single `blank` paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to working.

Change log:

- Use `MatchWholeWord = False` in replacing
- You do not have to select the target paragraph for replacing

***Note:*** If there more than one repetitive blank paragraphs in your document, you may need run the code several times.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim firstTerm As String
    Dim secondTerm As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim iStart As Long
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    firstTerm = "*start*"
    secondTerm = "*end*"
    With myRange.Find
        .Text = firstTerm
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute
        myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        iStart = myRange.End
        .Text = secondTerm
        .Execute
        myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
        myRange.Start = iStart
    End With
    With myRange.Find
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```